# How to reverse log scale on y axis in Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a violinplot in Seaborn with the y-axis scaled by np.log1p. I would like to reverse this using np.expm1() on the y-axis labels, but I do not know how to do this. Using sns.set() I can set the y-label but not the individual y values.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
v = sns.violinplot(x=total['Years in current job'], y=np.log1p(total['Maximum Open Credit']), order=['< 1 year', '1 year', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years', '6 years', '7 years', '8 years', '9 years', '10+ years'])
v.set_xticklabels(v.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.violinplot(y=np.log1p(tips["total_bill"]))
ax.set_yticklabels([f'{np.expm1(l):.2f}' for l in ax.get_yticks()])
```

[image]